# Cannot import nltk in Jupyter even though I can import it in Python Console

Tags: python, pip, installation, nltk, python-import

I installed `nltk` and seemed to successfully install. But when I try to import it, it says `no module named nltk`. However, when I try to reinstall it, it says requirement already satisfied. How could that be the case? What can I do to fix this? Thanks!

[image]

Additionally if I try to `import nltk` using python shell (under the same virtual environment that I am running the jupyter notebook from), I get the following:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this has something to do with different versions of Python. Can you try `%pip3 install nltk`?

Comment: This is what I get `Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nltk) (1.12.0)
Installing collected packages: nltk
Successfully installed nltk-3.4.5`

Comment: Can you do: `python3.7 -m pip install -U nltk`?

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik I get the following: `Requirement already up-to-date: nltk in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nltk) (1.12.0)`. Does this mean anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a problem to with the version of Python Jupyter is currently pointing to.

---

To fix the issue, make sure that both jupyter and pip are running under the same environment. For example, compare `which python` and `pip -V`

---

Also make sure that Python is pointing to the right path:

In your Jupyter Notebook, the output of

```
import sys

sys.version
```

should match your python version:

```
python --version
```

Comment: Okay, so I followed your suggestions. I attached the output above. The python versions seem to be the same, but the environments are different if I understand correctly? Is that the issue? Thank you very much.

Comment: @JaneSully Yes. For example you can force Jupyter to use specific version or something.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify do we want the output of `which python` or `pip -V` to change? My assumption is that we want `pip -V` to match `which python`? I guess I'm not sure what should be changed, and how? Thanks!

Comment: @JaneSully By the way consider `anaconda`. It might make your life easier when it comes to versions.